# Importing and concatenating arrays, then sequentially addin values in one column

Tags: arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have several space delimited arrays in .txt files I want to import them all from a folder, concatenate them in the correct order then take one column and make the values in one of the columns continue from the first one.

Basically if I have array 1

```
[1 2 3]
[2 2 3]
[3 2 3]
```

and array 2

```
[1 2 3]
[2 3 3]
[3 2 3]
```

I want a final array

```
[1 2 3]
[2 2 3]
[3 2 3]
[4 2 3]
[5 3 3]
[6 2 3]
```

Any ideas? It's really important that the final value of one column is added to ALL the values of the same column in the next array. In the third array, I want to ad the final value of the SECOND array and so on.

Oh yeah, I'm pretty new and so far I only have this, which makes the list of file names:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from os import listdir

mypath = raw_input('Enter directory path: ')
relevant_path = mypath

included_extenstions = ['txt']
file_names = [fn for fn in os.listdir(relevant_path)
    if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extenstions)]
sorted_file_names = sorted(file_names)
```

OK, now I have this:

```
included_extenstions = ['txt']
file_names = [fn for fn in os.listdir(relevant_path)
    if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extenstions)]
sorted_file_names = sorted(file_names)

loc_one = np.loadtxt(sorted_file_names[0])
loc_two = np.loadtxt(sorted_file_names[1])
loc_three = np.loadtxt(sorted_file_names[2])
loc_four = np.loadtxt(sorted_file_names[3])

loc_five = np.concatenate((loc_one, loc_two), axis = 0)
loc_five[-len(loc_two):,1] += loc_one[-1,1]

loc_six = np.concatenate((loc_five, loc_three), axis = 0)
loc_six[-len(loc_three):,1] += loc_five[-1,1]

loc_seven = np.concatenate((loc_six, loc_four), axis = 0)
loc_seven[-len(loc_four):,1] += loc_six[-1,1]
```

(arrays are all called loc_number) It seems very brute-force and unflexible. Also, if I run it several times it somehow stores what it did in the first run, so everything keep doubling - loc_seven the first time around gives the correct result, but loc_seven on the second run gives a concatenation of two loc_sevens (then 4 etc).

Comment: To start you can use [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy-loadtxt) and [numpy.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html#numpy.column_stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, concatenate your arrays:

```
In [16]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,2,3]])

In [17]: b = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,3],[3,2,3]])

In [18]: c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)

In [19]: c
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 3]])
```

Then, slice out the first column of the last `len(b)` rows and add `a`'s last row's first value:

```
In [20]: c[-len(b):,0] += a[-1,0]

In [21]: c
Out[21]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [5, 3, 3],
       [6, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you do that universally so that it would work for different numbers of imported arrays? Let's say I have 6 or more to process like this, any way to automate that with a loop?

Comment: If you have `a`, `b` and `c` to concatenate, first join `a` and `b`, then join `c` to the newly created array